# Errors in Multi class image classification using CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, classification, image-classification

I'm fairly new to CNN and python and I'm trying to classify images consisting of 3 classes. Whenever I try to train my model I get the error: TypeError: Cannot convert 0.6 to EagerTensor of dtype int64. I'm not fully sure what to make of this or how to fix it and would appreciate any help.

Here's the code :

```
train_gen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

validation_gen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator=train_gen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_df,
    "/Users/danieladegborioye/Documents/school/FIFTH YEAR/ENGR 418 Applied Machine learning /Lego_dataset_1/training/",
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='category',
    target_size=(150,150),
    class_mode="categorical",
    batch_size=32
)

validation_generator=validation_gen.flow_from_dataframe(
    validate_df,
    "/Users/danieladegborioye/Documents/school/FIFTH YEAR/ENGR 418 Applied Machine learning /Lego_dataset_1/training/",
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='category',
    target_size=(150,150),
    class_mode="categorical",
    batch_size=32
)


epochs=10
batch_size=10

history=modell.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=total_validate/batch_size,
    steps_per_epoch=total_train/batch_size,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is but I suggest you make sure the values in the category column are strings. use train_df['category']=train_df['category'].astype(str)

Answer (score 0):

If `batch_size` is greater than the `total_validate` or `total_train`, then `steps_per_epoch` will be less than 1 which is causing this `'TypeError: Cannot convert 0.6 to EagerTensor of dtype int64'`.